# How to request focus to a particular tab by default?

Tags: android, android-tablayout

I am using tabLayout in my application where I have created a view pager which sets to a `viewPagerAdapter` where I added the required fragments.

By default as I open the app the first tab is selected I want to show the third tab by default while opening the app so how should I do that?

Comment: have you tried setSelected() method?

Comment: Can you please post your code?

Comment: viewPager.setCurrentItem(2);

Comment: request focus is another event, you're speaking about select

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `myViewPager.setCurrentItem(2)` to open the third page. This must be done after the adapter has data, and is set on the ViewPager.

Comment: this takes care of selection not focus in my opinion

Comment: that's true - I think the OP was inaccurate with the question title; in the question body, it's clearer they meant selection.